# Positivity of certain polynomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, positivity

Consider the rational functions (in fact, polynomials)
$$F_n(q)=\frac1{(1-q)^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-q)^k\frac{2k+1}{n+k+1}\binom{2n}{n-k}
\prod_{j=0,\,j\neq k}^n\frac{1+q^{2j+1}}{1+q}.$$
The numbers $\frac{2k+1}{n+k+1}\binom{2n}{n-k}$ belong to a family of [Catalan triangle](https://oeis.org/A009766) of which the special case
$k=0$ yields the [Catalan numbers](https://oeis.org/A000108) $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$.

Of further interest is $F_n(1)=E_{2n}$, the [Euler numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number).

> Question. Is it true that $F_n(q)$ has positive coefficients? Experiments suggest so.