# Palindromicity of $q$-polynomials related to Catalan triangles

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials

The present problem comes from further consideration of my earlier questions, from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383663/looking-for-a-combinatorial-proof-for-an-identity-involving-q-catalan-triangle) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302450/prove-that-these-are-polynomials).

Start with the following variants of Catalan triangles
$\frac{2k+1}{n+k+1}\binom{2n}{n-k}$. Now, define the functions ([proven polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302450/prove-that-these-are-polynomials))
$$F_n(q)=\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{1+q^{2j-1}}{(1-q)(1-q^2)}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-q)^k(1+q^{2n+1})}{1+q^{2k+1}}\frac{2k+1}{n+k+1}\binom{2n}{n-k}.$$

> **QUESTION.** Are the polynomials $F_n(q)$ [palindromic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial)?

Comment: Your title says unimodal while the text of your question asks about palindromicity. Of course, both are interesting/reasonable.

Comment: @SamHopkins: thank you. Edited accordingly now.

Comment: It seems empirically that $F_n(1)$ is the Euler number $E_{2n}$, which equals the number of alternating permutations of $1,2,\dots,2n$. Do the coefficients have a combinatorial interpretation in terms of Euler numbers or something else counted by $E_{2n}$? The sequence of coefficients for $n=2,3,4$ are (2,1,2), (5,6,14,11,14,6,5), and (14,28,76,107,172,185,221,185,172,107,76,28,14).

Comment: It is easy to see that $F_{n}\left(\frac{1}{q}\right)=q^{n(n+1)} F_{n}(q)$. So it suffices to show that the polynomial $F_{n}(q)$ is of order $n(n+1)$ to show that it is palindromic.

Comment: @JohannesTrost: do you mean $q^{n(n+1)}F_n(1/q)=F_n(q)$? A polynomial satisfying this is palindromic whatever its degree.

Comment: @Richard Stanley Sorry for the typo. Concerning the degree, you are right, of course. The correct version of my comment would be: By insertion it is easy to see that $ F_{n}\left( \frac{1}{q} \right)=q^{-n(n+1)}F_{n}(q)$. Therefore, if  $F_{n}(q)$ are polynomials, they are palindromic.